# How to transfer commits between branches on one line

Tags: git

I need to move commits from one branch to another and delete the first one.

Is:

```
Develop--BranchA--CommitA1--CommitA2
                                    \
                                     BranchB--CommitB1--CommitB2
```

Should:

```
Develop
       \
        Branch2--CommitA1--CommitA2--CommitB1--CommitB2
```

I try to do this through `git cherry-pick` but it does not work

There is a conflict in one file.

I'm fixing a conflict with commit and trying to do a `cherry-pick` again

I get information about the same conflict again

Comment: Where did the `Branch2` commit come from?  Is that supposed to be `BranchA`, or if not can you explain what is happening here?

Comment: Branches are not commits. They are merely pointers to commits (in the chain of commits), and these pointers can be updated. With that in mind, could you clarify the question? Also after you resolve the conflict you need to add/commit the changes and run git cherry-pick --continue